# independence of observations for logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, assumptions

I am currently writing my bachelor thesis ans I've recently gotten into ML and logistic regression and I'm a little confused as to the assumption that the observations are independent. I found this post: https://towardsdatascience.com/assumptions-of-logistic-regression-clearly-explained-44d85a22b290.
It describes how the assumption is confirmed when the points are randomly distributed around the zero line. In my dataset, however, the plot looks like this:
[image]
Two groups can be identified. And there are no points between dev. resid. = 0 and dev. resid. = 0.75  Can I still assume here that the observations are independent of each other?

Unfortunately, the other posts in this forum and on other websites could not answer my question

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't confound "randomly distributed" with "uniformly distributed."  You definitely have a bimodal distribution of residuals, but there's no visual evidence that the residuals depend on "Index number."

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the answer exactly. Can I now assume that the observations are independent of each other because there's no visual evidence that the residuals depend on the Index number? As I said, I have little experience and no other contribution has helped me with my question.

Comment: The vertical lines make me think there are long sequences of 1's that would not be expected under independence. Probably of 0s too, but those are harder to see. I might suggest fitting some kind of time series model that is specifically tailored to logistic regression, then examine the size of the time series dependence parameter, and also compare the fits of the time series and independence models using likelihood -based measures.